# Should error section be in a Blockquote or Sample Code?

Tags: discussion, edits

I always edit that type of question that OP reports his/her error as a code block, and I change it to a blockquote.

Am I right, or it should remain as a code block?

For example this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13310789

Comment: I personally use code blocks unless the error has very long lines, in which case I use blockquotes since horizontally scrolling 3000 pixels doesn't work very well.

Comment: "MySQL" and "MySQL Server" do not need to be in backticks though...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker , I think it makes it more readable to backticks the specific names

Comment: @Carpetsmoker IMO, If you keep the error message in a `Sample Code` block, I'd suggest adding `<!-- language: lang-none -->` above it to stop the default color coding as it's meaningless in this case. Otherwise, as what happened in the example above, you get random color coding that looks awkward and doesn't provide any benefit.

Comment: @Arman [Don't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/176646) [do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/234299) [that.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322098/176646)

Comment: Also see [Should console output be formatted as code sample or as blockquote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190092/234299) (MetaSE), [Correct way to format errors messages (or stacktraces)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141336/234299) (MetaSE), [Should exceptions resulting from code be inside code snippets?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322699/176646) (MetaSO), [Should error logs be formatted as code or quote?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185853/234299) (MetaSE)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the error. There are some errors that should ALWAYS be in code blocks, since they are hard to read otherwise. And otherwise, you might have to manually escape things.

In your case, it doesn't matter either way.

I do have a complaint with another part of that edit. `I` suggest not putting `Proper Nouns` in `Back Ticks` since this is really annoying to a lot of people on `Stack Overflow` and other `Stack Exchange` sites, as mentioned by `Carpetsmoker` and `ThisSuitIsBlackNot`.

---

For an example of an error that should always be in a code block, I use the error from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38883794/6083675) question (picked because I recently edited it).

The error looks really bad as a block quote:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     Process: com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol, PID: 1666
>     com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>         at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42)
>         at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:58)
>         at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:52)
>         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
>         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
>         at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
>         at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
>         at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
>         at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
>         at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42) 
>         at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:58) 
>         at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:52) 
>         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60) 
>         at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
>         at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Compare that with:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol, PID: 1666
  com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
      at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42)
      at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:58)
      at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:52)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1
      at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:338)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:79)
      at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768) 
      at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717) 
      at com.kosalgeek.android.json.JsonConverter.toArrayList(JsonConverter.java:42) 
      at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:58) 
      at com.glorystone.mojtaba.gol.search$1$1.onResponse(search.java:52) 
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60) 
      at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30) 
      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99) 
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

(Note that I personally am OK with code highlighting in error messages for the most part. I wouldn't add code highlighting, but it's not required to remove it in most cases.)