# BAD "suggested edit" approved by reviewers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Most of the time it happens that *users who are reviewing suggested edits are just scanning the text and if it looks good, the edit is accepted.*

This works in majority of cases, but sometimes, **some invalid edits gets approval and this changes whole point of the question**. What should be done under these circumstances? Should we edit it back to the original content, though it would look strange because that edit was approved by 4-5 other community members?

---

***Consider this example:***

[Stop PHP from adding backslashes to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970728/stop-php-from-adding-backslashes-to-string)

1. A user was facing some problem that PHP keeps on adding unnecessary backslashes to some of his characters. He even appended the regex with a comment as: *It is adding backslashes where I don't expect them. What's a workaround this?* [source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38970728/revisions#spacer-5e5be842-41fa-4d9f-b6a8-431c061b27b9)

   [image: original question]
2. Another Stack Overflow user edited his question and removed extra backslashes from his content. Since this user didn't have 2k reputation, this edit was placed as a suggested edit. However **this was the original problem that OP was facing.** [source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38970728/revisions#spacer-6306ab85-e6c3-4868-92ec-89b7f20c8ea5)

   [image: User suggesting wrong edit]
3. It was strange to see that this edit was approved by Stack Overflow community members because from the first look, it looked like a sort of improved formatting. It looked like the content within backticks was placed in blockquote (seemed good), but that changed the whole point of the question. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13352173)

   [image: Community members approving wrong edit]
4. Finally (and fortunately), the OP came back and replaced the wrong edit with image of his actual output. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38970728/revisions)

   [image: OP reverting edit]

Now in this case, fortunately the OP came back and improved that edit. But WHAT IF the user was completely new?

Shouldn't be there any **"Review Edit Once Again"**, or **Flag edit for moderator's attention** functionality that will bring back the attention of community members or moderators saying that the edit which was approved or rejected should be considered once again?

Comment: You mean, something *other* than the "rollback" feature?

Comment: And no one even removed the *Thanks in advance* :(

Comment: @CodyGray I think a rollback is for something else. When you hover on it, it says **sets the current revision to this version of the post, resetting any "rude or abusive" flags"**. Nothing here was rude or offensive. Instead there was a **clean** edit approved by community users. However, in this example, it's absolutely clear that this edit was wrongly proposed, but sometimes it may be hard to figure out whether or not the edit changed the meaning of question and requires OP to review it. Moreover, what if the edit was proposed on an old, accepted answered question.

Comment: Sigh. Clarification about the feature's behavior regarding flags has apparently been added to the tooltip trying to be extra helpful, but that just made the tooltip more confusing overall. No, rollbacks have nothing inherently to do with rude or abusive flags. It *just so happens* that when your roll back an edit, it resets the rude and abusive flags. But that just makes sense. It should not be taken to imply that such is the *purpose* of the rollback feature. Any edit that is bad or unwanted should be rolled back this way. Why would it being an "old, accepted, answered question" matter?

Comment: "But WHAT-IF the user was completely new?" Then you could have performed the edit yourself. You have the rep. Community moderation is a staple of SO. It's well known that bad edits regularly get approved. Go for it!

Comment: @NathanOliver If that's the thing you notice most in this question... I don't know what to say. You may be too far gone.

Comment: @jpmc26 Do note that I didn't go and edit it out myself :).  My point was that if you are going to improve the post, improve all of it.  *Thanks in adavance* adds nothing to the question so it should be removed when doing other edits.

Comment: @CodyGray I come across this occasionally, and have been rolling back. When rolling back there is no option to add a msg describing why we're doing that.  Should we also notify the person who made the edit, or maybe more importantly the person(s) who approved it, so they know to be more careful in future?  If so, how - a comment on the post?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I'll address your feature requests first:

> "Review Edit Once Again"

We trust users with 2k+ rep to make and approve good edits. Supposedly. I think suggested edits already need more approve votes than other sites do.

> Flag edit for moderator's attention

We already have this feature. It's right next to the close button on the actual question page.

---

Now for the edit:

> Another SO user edited his question and removed extra backslashes from his content.

Not really. Look at it differently:

> [image: Nothing really changed]

The user simply changed the way things were rendered. The change in rendering is what broke things.

This is a misunderstanding in the way that markdown works.

One might hope that users with 2k rep and even one with 4k rep would understand the system better, but you'd be hoping in vain.

---

Even ignoring the fact that the format was broken, there was no reason to approve the edit. The one newline was really the only improvement, since the other part of the edit simply moved the one phrase around.

Also, there is no reason to put regexes as quotes. It was the OP's regex, and regexes are code.

I have fixed things (including removing the "thanks in advance"). The code should not be a picture, but I don't fault the user, who may not have realized their question was edited. I chose to use `` back ` ` ticks `` because you can see the entire regex that way.

Comment: "Also, there is no reason to put regexes as quotes. It was the OP's regex, and regexes are code." - This. I have seen *far* too many things end up in blockquotes lately.

Comment: I've seen people move, say, tracebacks into blockquotes. I think I've even had someone change from a codeblock to blockquote. Naturally I rolled that back ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I tend to put a stack trace in a codeblock in a block quote.  Should I stop doing that?

Comment: @RoadieRich For short errors, it should be OK. There are some errors, however, that need their indentation and side scrolling to be legible. I wrote about this [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332228/6083675).

Comment: @Laurel: Code block nested in a blockquote should still have those, no?

Comment: @BenVoigt Perhaps the editor didn't know how to correctly format code blocks inside blockquotes?  It _is_ a bit weird, after all.  (`>`, one space, line break (optional), and then four more spaces to use code block formatting doesn't really feel all that natural, at least not to me.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Oh, I guess I misread that then. It's a bit excessive, but I guess it's better than just a block quote. It's one of those things that I might change if I fix other things. (Block quotes should mostly be used as part of attribution. It's usually assumed that we know you didn't write the error. Nobody will in trouble for "plagiarizing" an error message.)

Comment: Thanks for teaching me how to put back ticks inside back ticks :)

Comment: @JustinTime Select code, CTRL+K, CTRL+Q

Comment: @Justin Oh, that's useful to know.