# How to help cancel a wrong edit? (from a new-ish users perspective)

Tags: discussion

I've encountered the following issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62470412/revisions): someone edited a post inappropriately (placed backticks in the wrong place), and the edit got approved. ***Important: I'm not an editor, nor OP.*** Is there anything I can do to help recover the post? (Another edit on top would not have 6 characters, so I can't even suggest it)
Obviously, this would be a problem only if the OP is not a completely new user, but what to do just in case? What to do if he does actually not understand how all of that works?

[This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332552/10713244) did not answer my question - the question is asked with an imaginatory perspective of a new(ish) user in mind.

How suitable is flagging the whole answer as a one that "In need of moderator intervention"? That is the only solution I see even remotely fit, since flags are meant to be used to close bad questions/answers, and I can't find a way to flag an edit itself. How'd that affect flag stats of a user that raised the flag himself, would it just be marked as "declined"?

Here's a screenshot of the exact edit, in case it gets deleted:
[image: A screenshot]

Comment: i mean, the author approved it, so... it's basically as if the author themselves made the edit. The right thing to do here would be to fix it, not raise a flag.

Comment: @KevinB How to fix it? The fix would be only 2 chars, you need 6...

Comment: Anyone with enough rep to edit freely can do it, otherwise you can leave a comment prompting the author to do it.

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, that makes sense... Thanks

Comment: Another option is flagging for moderator attention, which may seem like an overreaction but also allows the mod to notify the two users that approved this edit of their mistake (else this will unfortunately go unnoticed for them). That's specific for when another low-rep user edited, else just @ comment and notify the editor of his mistake.

Comment: @ErikA That's exactly what I've suggested, the question is: how much of an overkill would that be?

Comment: Well, not that much, as we can't notify reviewers making mistakes ourselves, and bad reviewers are a lot worse than no reviewers. But perhaps a mod can weigh in here. I wouldn't worry too much about declined flags, if you get loads of them you can get limited in your ability to flag but that only really happens if you systematically keep flagging wrong and flag a lot I think.

Comment: Um, what's the problem with that edit again?

Comment: @pppery `(files)` should be inside the backticks as well

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the post, but it's likely I wouldn't have noticed the problem if I were reviewing the edit given I didn't notice it here.

Comment: @ErikA Unless, as has happened to me, the moderator then inappropriately rejects your flag because the OP accepted it, as if that made the edit & other approvals OK.

Comment: I just posted this there: @ *editor* There is no reason to edit names from code to have code format in text. It's purely a matter of unimportant style preference. The edit should be been rejected as 'adds no improvement[ & even 'conflicts with poster intent'. Also: Please do not make such small edits either until you have enough rep to not have your edit reviewed by others, you are taking the away from reviewing constructive & much more effective edits. It doesn't matter that here the poster accepted the edit.

Comment: When I leave comments like that and there have been non-poster review accepters I flag a moderator about telling them & the editor & link my comment.

Comment: @KevinB The author didn't approve, 2 others did.